# Where do I pay taxes when payed by Finnish company as German citizen?

Tags: taxes, germany, european-union, finland

**If I am paid by a company that is based in Finland while I am a German citizen, where do I pay taxes and to which government?  If to only one, do I need to tell about it?**

I am a citizen of Germany.  I live there and I am employed by a German company which is my main place of work.  I am part owner of a company based in Finland which will pay me some amount of money during the next few months.  I work remotely for the company that I partially own.

As I understand it, based on [this](https://www.bundesfinanzministerium.de/Content/DE/Standardartikel/Themen/Steuern/Internationales_Steuerrecht/Staatenbezogene_Informationen/Laender_A_Z/Finnland/2017-04-28-Finnland-Abkommen-DBA-Gesetz.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=2) bilateral agreement (section 14), I need to pay taxes **in Germany, and not Finland. If this is correct, do I also need to tell the Finnish government about the taxes that I pay in Germany?** I am registered as one of the owners of the company in Finland.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you pay taxes in germany on your income, when you live there for 183 days(+). When finland don't have special taxes on the kind of income you get, you shouldn't pay any taxes there but maybe you have report ad testify it to them. (especially if the taxes are paid automatically with the payment you get)

Comment: The other company will actually pay you in a way that doesn't deduct taxes, pushing the burden of paying taxes onto you. You need to make sure you save enough money to pay your taxes in germany.